# Wordpress Media Uploader: How to refresh media uploader content

Tags: wordpress

We have added custom tab after Media Library tab in wordpress media uploader popup but the content of tab not getting refreshed after uploads.

It requires full page reload for the update content in media uploader popup.

here is the custom tab that we have added.

[image]

Comment: add all your code you added for new tab. we can't guess, what you coded

Answer (score 1):

A user was facing a similar issue, you could use this plugin, everything is explained here:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/refresh-media-library-after-manual-ftp-upload

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: So the OP left after finding the solution, without marking any answer as a valid... good @jaguwalapratik

Comment: OPs behavior wasn't nice, but if it matters, this is most definitely not the solution because it describes a completely different problem.